# How to fix the bug React-Redux: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions? I need clarity on the same

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

In product action file, I have the list product function exporting all the three actions in try and except block. But when importing them in useEffect prompty through dispatch (useDispatch) I am getting Actions must be plain objects. If I am correct, the list product itself at the base is an object. But I am not able to understand why this error is coming. Could you help me with the same?

File : productAction.js

```
import axios from "axios";
import {
  PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST,
  PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
  PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,
} from "../constants/productConstants";
 
export const listProducts = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST });
    const { data } = await axios.get("/api/products/");
    dispatch({
      type: PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

File : HomeScreen.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import Product from "../components/Product";
import { listProducts } from "../actions/productActions";
 
function HomeScreen() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listProducts());
  }, []);
  const products = [];
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Latest Products</h1>
      <Row>
        {products.map((product) => (
          <Col key={product._id} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
            <Product product={product} />
          </Col>
        ))}
      </Row>
    </div>
  );
}
 
export default HomeScreen;
```

File: Store

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import { productListReducer } from "./reducers/productReducers";

const reducer = combineReducers({
  productList: productListReducer,
});

const initialState = {};
const middleware = [thunk];
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware())
);

export default store;
```

Error Screenshot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEnh8.png)

Answer (score 1):

you didn't apply middleware.
Please check store file.
https://prnt.sc/1omysnu

Comment: Thanks. It helped to solve the problem. I had to spread the list and pass the variable and it worked

Answer (score 0):

In file store.js you haven't used thunk anywhere.

```js
applyMiddleware() //This is empty, error is here i guess.
```

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering on the un-assigned variable, but was not sure on the same.